# Error in pip install torchvision on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

on [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/), installing on Windows 10, conda and Cuda 9.0.

cmd did not complain when i ran `conda install pytorch cuda90 -c pytorch`, then when I ran `pip3 install torchvision` I get this error message.

```
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in PATHTOFILE\python35\lib\site-packages (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in PATHTOFILE\python35\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (1.12.0+mkl)
Requirement already satisfied: six in PATHTOFILE\python35\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (1.10.0)
Collecting pillow>=4.1.1 (from torchvision)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/d2/d27a21bd3e64db1ca1dc7dc16026a16d77f5c3ffca9ec619eddeea7c47ce/Pillow-5.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting torch (from torchvision)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/e9/bac4204fe9cb1a002ec6140b47f51affda1655379fe302a1caef421f9846/torch-0.1.2.post1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\USERNAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a70g611u\torch\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError(README)
    RuntimeError: PyTorch does not currently provide packages for PyPI (see status at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/566).

    Please follow the instructions at http://pytorch.org/ to install with miniconda instead.


    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USERNAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a70g611u\torch\
```

Anyone got this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it by running the following

`pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu90/torch-0.4.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

`pip3 install torchvision`

This weirdly fixes the problem. No idea why. Next time just try to run everything on `pip`

Answer (score 10):

I tried to use:

```
pip install torchvision
```

but it didn't work for me.
So, I googled this problem more carefully and found another solution:

```
pip install --no-deps torchvision
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Update:
I want to add: "--no-deps" means that no dependencies packages will be downloaded.

Answer (score 8):

The windows version of pytorch was never uploaded to PyPi for Windows because of the size limits. So when installing you need to use -f or --force-link to the PyTorch wheel:

```
pip install torch===1.5.0 torchvision===0.6.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works well to use "pip install --no-deps torchvision".